# Get the first and last element of sequences inside an level of an multindex pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a series that has a status for something that can be True or False. It has a MultiIndex with the first level for ID, the second for an episode in each ID and an a third for the Date when the Status was recorded.

```
ID  Episode Date        Status
foo 1       2019-02-01  False
            2019-02-02  True
            2019-02-03  True
            2019-02-04  False
    2       2019-02-05  True
            2019-02-06  True
            2019-02-07  False
    3       2019-02-08  False
            2019-02-09  True
            2019-02-10  True
bar 1       2019-03-03  False
            2019-03-04  True
    2       2019-03-05  True
            2019-03-06  True
            2019-03-07  False
            2019-03-08  True
            2019-03-09  False
```

I would like to extract to an Dataframe the Dates for when the Status, in an episode, starts to be True and when it stops to be True. The result, for this example, should be something like this:

```
 ID Episode Start Dates             End Dates       
foo 1       2019-02-02              2019-03-03          
    2       2019-02-05              2019-02-06  
    3       2019-02-09              2019-02-10
bar 1       2019-03-04              2019-03-04
    2       2019-03-05, 2019-03-08  2019-03-06, 2019-03-08
```

Comment: check with your output bar - 2

Comment: Thanks, already corrected

Comment: Why last line 2019-03-09 has been selected

Comment: Another typo... I've tried to do an example with only a day with "true" and made a mistake with it...

Comment: I have add a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with using `groupby` with `cumsum` create the internal key for group, next steps we do filter base on all `True` value in df , then we do another round `groupby` with the new key and `first` `last` , `join` the result

```
s=(~df.Status).groupby(level=['ID','Episode']).cumsum().reset_index()

s[df.Status.values].groupby(['ID','Episode','Status'])['Date'].agg(['first','last']).groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(','.join)
Out[104]: 
                             first                   last
ID  Episode                                              
bar 1                   2019-03-04             2019-03-04
    2        2019-03-05,2019-03-08  2019-03-06,2019-03-08
foo 1                   2019-02-02             2019-02-03
    2                   2019-02-05             2019-02-06
    3                   2019-02-09             2019-02-10
```

Comment: Thanks. At least isn’t a simple solution that was escaping me. Now I only need to understand the answer.

Comment: @JoãoColaço yep , if you have any question just let me know

Comment: how I understand this answer is, there is a `cumsum` on the booleans that has the effect of mapping [True, False] in a +1, +0. This mean that e.g [False, False, True, True, False] get mapped to [0, 0, 1, 2, 2]. Afterwards are used the aggregation functions 'first' and 'last' that gets the first and last time a number appear in the mapped serie. In the example [0, 0, 1, 2 , 2] the number 0 appears the first time in 0, the number 1 appears the first time in index 2 and so on. At the end is used again an aggregative function with .join. A interesting but quite convoluted answer!

Comment: Close. The accumulation is done on the False values so the True ones will have always the same number `(~df.Status)`. In the next line this series/df is filtered for only the rows with True values `s[df.Status.values]`. After this the series will have different values for each succession of True in the Status. This will enable grouping around this values, get the first and last date, and finally group by episode and aggregate the results in only one line.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `pandas.Series.shift` that shift your `Status` column by one.

```
df['prev_Status'] = df['Status'].shift(1)
df['next_Status'] = df['Status'].shift(-1)

                    Status  prev_Status next_Status
Date            
foo 1   2019-02-01  False   NaN     True
        2019-02-02  True    False   True
        2019-02-03  True    True    False
        2019-02-04  False   True    True
2       2019-02-05  True    False   True
        2019-02-06  True    True    False
```

Once is shifted you can query as intended when `True` is being turned on

```
df.query('prev_Status=="False"').query('Status=="True"').groupby(level=[0,1]).Date.agg(','.join)

bar  1    2019-03-04
     2    2019-03-08
foo  1    2019-02-02
     2    2019-02-05
     3    2019-02-09
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Or when is being turned off

```
df.query('Status=="True"').query('next_Status=="False"').groupby(level=[0,1]).Date.agg(','.join)

bar  2    2019-03-06,2019-03-08
foo  1               2019-02-03
     2               2019-02-06
     3               2019-02-10
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

One could argue that this is less efficient than the other (really good) answer but *easier to understand*.